# How to Use CoffeeScript with Phoenix Framework?

Tags: coffeescript, phoenix-framework, brunch

I need to integrate a few CoffeeScript functions with my Phoenix application.

How do I get CoffeeScript files to compile and run alongside my application?

I know that phoenix uses Brunch for the asset pipeline - is there a brunch package or something for CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Phoenix "[Static Assets](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets)" page has instructions on how to set this up. Scroll a little more than halfway down that page.

Basically:

- Add `coffee-script-brunch` to `package.json` above `javascript-brunch`.
- Run `npm install`.
- Create `.coffee` files in `web/static/js` (make sure they are referenced in `app.js`).
- I also had to restart the Phoenix server.